How to identify independent subsets in a transition table
I have a table that describes the way to move from one economic classification to another. It looks like that (but a numeric identifier is not mandatory):
df0 <- data.frame(
  old=c("a","b","b","c","c","d","e","f","g","h","h","i"),
  new=c("A","A","B","B","C","C","C","D","D","E","F","G"))

meaning that old "h" is spread into ("E","F"), "f" and "g" are merged into "D", "i" is simply transformed into "G", while "a","b","c","d","e" are involved in a group of merges that are not splittable into independent events. That is "a" is merged with "b" into "A" but "b" is just partially involved here as there it is actually spread into "A" and "B" and so on...
My problem: I would like to give some identifier to the different subsets that are practically created into the column 'old': the four subsets ("a","b","c","d","e"),("f","g"),("h"),("i").
The desired output could be like that:
data.frame(
  old= c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i"),
  id = c(  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  2,  2,  3,  4))

I already have written a solution with base-R but it involves taking a set intersection from within a double loop and is not efficient with large classifications. I wonder whether somebody wrote a low level langage solution to that kind of problem in some R package or, best for me, if there is a solution using SQL under duckdb. After all it was written that SQL was a full power langage able to handle any algorithm :-).
Thanks

Please provide your desired output based on your example input

Sounds like you're describing a graph theory problem. Create an igraph::graph_from_data_frame() and take its components().
library(igraph)
g  <- graph_from_data_frame(df0)

(grps <- components(g)$membership)
# a b c d e f g h i A B C D E F G 
# 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 3 4 1 1 1 2 3 3 4 

As you can see, the membership of the old (lower case) IDs correspond to the sets you describe: ("a","b","c","d","e"),("f","g"),("h"),("i"). You can also see which of these groups the new IDs correspond to.
You can add this as a new column to your data frame:
within(df0, grp  <- grps[old])
#    old new grp
# 1    a   A   1
# 2    b   A   1
# 3    b   B   1
# 4    c   B   1
# 5    c   C   1
# 6    d   C   1
# 7    e   C   1
# 8    f   D   2
# 9    g   D   2
# 10   h   E   3
# 11   h   F   3
# 12   i   G   4

You can also plot the graph for a visual sense of each group. Regarding your question in the comment, yes, you can plot whether they were are in the original or new group with an ifelse() statement depending on whether the vertices are in the old new group, using the igraph::V() function.
V(g)$color <- ifelse(names(V(g)) %in% df0$old, "yellow", "green")
plot(g)



What is grps?

@Friede oops I removed some code producing a list when I saw the question had been edited to include expected output - fixed now, thanks.

@SamR. Thanks  a lot for your quick answer. Is there a simple way to change the color of the nodes in the plot? I would like to have just two different colors for the starting nodes ("a", "b"...) and the ending ones ("A", "B",...)

@Nicolas2 yes - see my edit.
